# Unified Accounts with POS

Tags: polkadot, account, evm, pos, proof-of-stake

is there any repository who are implementing **unified accounts** with **Proof of Stake (POS)** consensus except moonbeam.

we want H160 type of account for both Substrate and EVM Transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two `H160` account networks.

But with the different staking mechanism.

- https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0

  - https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-2.0/tree/main/pallet/staking
- https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam

  - https://github.com/PureStake/moonbeam/tree/master/pallets/parachain-staking